# Using a GPS location transmitter how do I use current and historical data to predict when a bus will reach a bus stop?

Tags: node.js, arduino, gps

I'm building a bus tracker. We have a wonderful $100 Arduino GPS tracking device with cell phone transmitter that works great. What we need now is an algorithm to determine for a public bus to each stop. How do I do this? Do I just use average speed? Do I use historical data to determine average speed during rush hour? We are trying to make an open source solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll never have too much information.

Depending on your bus frequency, if you have multiple buses you can use them to estimate the current traffic flow and with that make estimations based on your historical data on similar traffic conditions.

It's harder to make real time estimations based on your current gps data. Average speed usually is not good enough, and `kallman filters` give the best linear estimations.